# Model of ZF with Infinite Descending Chain

Tags: set-theory, model-theory

Models of ZF satisfy per definition the **Axiom of Regularity** (also known as Axiom of Foundation): "Every non-empty set contains an element disjoint from it."

To the best of my knowledge, from this one can prove the following **theorem**: "There does not exist a sequence $(x_n)_{n \in \omega}$ such that $x_{n+1} \in x_n$ for all $n \in \omega$."

I am currently working through the book "Model Theory" by Chang and Keisler. Now I am stuck at exercise 2.1.7. which states: "Show that every model of ZF is elementary equivalent to a model $(A,E)$ which has an infinite sequence $...Ex_2Ex_1Ex_0$."

Now I am confused because I think this is a contradiction: On the one hand $(A,E)$ is elementary equivalent to the original model, in particular we should have $(A,E) \models$ ZF. But on the other hand it does not satisfy the theorem I stated above. Where is my mistake? How can one solve this exercise?

Thank you very much in advance!

**Edit:** I managed to solve the exercise in the following way: Let $(M,\varepsilon)$ be a model of ZF. Consider the language $\mathcal{L} = \{\in\}$ of set theory and the new language $\mathcal{L}' = \mathcal{L} \cup \{c_i\mid i \in \omega\}$, where the $c_i$ ($i \in \omega$) are distinct constant symbols. We look at a theory of $\mathcal{L}'$:

$\Sigma = $ ZF $ \cup$ $\{\sigma_n \mid n \in \omega\}$, where $\sigma_n$ is the sentence $c_{n+1} \in c_n$ for $n \in \omega$.

If we can show that $\Sigma$ has a model, we are done. By the compactness theorem it suffices to prove this for every finite subtheory $\Sigma'$ of $\Sigma$. But in $\Sigma'$ only finitely many $\sigma_n$ and therefore only finitely many constant symbols $c_0,...,c_m$ appear. If we now set the natural number $i$ as the interpretation of $c_i$ in $(M,\varepsilon)$ for every $i \in \{0,...,m\}$, we have a model $(M,\varepsilon,0,1,...,m)$ of $\Sigma'$.

But still I am confused about how this is compatible with the above theorem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First I think the solution you provided is correct and this is usually the way such exercises are proven.

Then about your confusion it is a phenomenon that often appears when working in model theory. In short, the solution is that $\omega$ is not the same in the model $M$ of $ZF$ than in the model $M'$ of $\Sigma$ whose existence you just proved. Thus, even if there is an "infinite sequence of inclusions" indexed by $\omega$, the index set $\omega$ is the one from $M$ and not from $M'$.

Edit: It has been mentioned in the comments that another phenomenon can also happen: I said above that the set denoted by $\omega$ can change; it can also be the case that the set $\omega$ remains the same but you don't have enough functions in your model, and in that case you would not be able to define in $M'$ the mapping $n\mapsto c_n$.

It is maybe easier to see why the apparent contradiction is not a real contradiction by looking at (a model for) non-standard integers. If you choose a non-standard number $N$ in this model, this number has a predecessor $N-1$, and it is easy to verify that $N-1$ is itself non-standard. You can then continue the same process "indefinitely" and you will always get a new non-standard integer, which in particular is not $0$.
If you take for $\omega$ the set from your standard model then you will indeed be able to construct a decreasing sequence indexed by this $\omega$, but if you take the correct $\omega$ (i.e. the one from your non-standard model) you won't be able to define your sequence past the index $N$.

Comment: (N.B.: I'm not an expert in set theory.) Are you guaranteed that the $\omega$ in $M'$ is non-standard? Could it not be that it has a standard $\omega$, but that the model just does not have the mapping $n \mapsto c_n^{M'}$ internally?

Comment: @MeesdeVries: Indeed that is possible.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I also recognized something else: Is it possible that the problem is the non-transitivity of the constructed model $M'$?

Comment: @Daniel: More generally, it is the fact that the relation of the model is not *truely* well-founded, but just internally well-founded. This may be confusing, but confusion is good, it means that you are forced to work closely with the definitions and are less likely to make mistakes. To make your confusion even worse. or maybe clarify where internal/external properties make a difference, note that one can have a model of ZF whose natural numbers are in fact an uncountable set (this is an easy use of compactness or ultrapowers). But internally, the integers are all finite.

Comment: To add to the confusion, you can also create a model of the real numbers such that the cardinality of this model is countable. In this example the bijection from the "new" set of real numbers to the set of integers is not in your model and so internally the set of real numbers is uncountable although externally it is countable.